# Using MPI Ibcast with multiple roots

Tags: c, mpi

I have an assignment with mpi.

In the assignment a slave must share some data to all the other slaves.

Let tasks = {1,2,3}

Task 1 broadcasts a message to all other tasks using Ibcast with root set to 1.
At the same time, task 2 broadcasts a message to all other slaves using Ibcast with root set to 2.

After a while, all the tasks do
For (i : tasks | where i != myRank)
       Use  Ibcast to recive message from root I

I Have a code written in c doing the example above.
The code works only if 1 task broadcasts a message,
but if two tasks are broadcasting messages at the same time (before, any other task has received any message)
I’m getting that the request never completes ( using mpi test function on the request handler from ibcast - in the foreach loop).

I’m not sure if I’m doing something wrong or mpi Ibcast does not provide expected behavior in this case.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [so] It's hard to say what's gone wrong. For example, why are you setting your root ranks to 1 and 2... what's the world size of your default communicator? please share an [mcve] that reflects your problem so that we can help

Comment: It all tasks broadcast to all tasks, then you can achieve that in one shot with `MPI_Iallgather()`.